# drift diffusion model with flanker conflict

Tags: ddms, dmcs

I'm trying to analyze my flanker data using  Diffusion Model of Conflict (DMC), beside conflict/ non-conflict condition I have 2 more variable (2*2*2), and I want to know if the model parameters are different in each condition. I'm using DMCfun R package and I used "dmcObservedData", "dmcCombineObservedData" and "dmcFit" for each condition.

1. How do I compare the parameters?
2. Is it better to apply dmcFit on all the condition together?

thank you

Avigail

I tried to create new data frame with 4 rows and the DMC parameters, but I don't know what next